# I'm trying to display an image in arcade python, why is it not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcade

```
width = 1400
height = 950
arcade_title = "r/pics"

arcade.open_window(width, height, arcade_title)

arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)
img = arcade.load_texture('google.jpeg')
arcade.draw_texture_rectangle (700, 475, 700, 700, img)

arcade.start_render()

arcade.finish_render()

arcade.run()
```

This is my code. When i run it no image is displayed. The window just stays white.

Comment: I've never used arcade, but the fact that the `start_render()` and `finish_render()` calls are adjacent sets an alarm in my head.  Are your draw functions supposed to be between those calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick edit worked for me (as I stated in my comment):

```
width = 1400
height = 950
arcade_title = "r/pics"

arcade.open_window(width, height, arcade_title)

arcade.start_render()

arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)
img = arcade.load_texture('google.jpeg')
arcade.draw_texture_rectangle (700, 475, 700, 700, img)

arcade.finish_render()

arcade.run()
```